# Simple broken For Each Loop in VB6

Tags: collections, foreach, vb6

I am writing a Contains method for vb6 collections that hold strings.

However I cannot get the syntax right on my foreach.

[image]

What should I change?

Comment: you are using VB.NET declaration syntax in VB6.  `Dim Thing as Object // For Each thing in Col`

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Function Contains(col as Collection, key as Variant) as Boolean

   Dim thing as Object '// this is the key

   For Each thing in col
      If CStr(key) = CStr(thing) then
         Contains = True
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next

   Contains = False
End Function
```